# Export MongoDB to CSV using Node.js but losing some column

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, export-to-csv

I want to export table to csv from mongodb using this script:

```
const mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
const fastcsv = require("fast-csv");
const fs = require("fs");
let url = "mongodb://...."

mongodb.connect(
  url,
  { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true },
  (err, client) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    client
      .db("mydb")
      .collection("mycsv")
      .find({})
      .toArray((err, data) => {
        if (err) throw err;

        console.log(data);
        fastcsv
          .write(data, { headers: true })
          .on("finish", function() {
            console.log("Write to mycsv.csv successfully!");
          })
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream("mycsv.csv"));

        client.close();
      });
  }
);
```

But I lost some column, what I know is the column that loses is the column with many null values (first 100 rows value of that columns is null).

Comment: Can you provide the data structure of the documents and which columns contain `null` values?

Comment: Have  a look at my solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/59799747/10831557

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are not providing any header information to fast-csv. In the docs it states:

```
> headers: {null|boolean|string[]} = null:
>    If true then the headers will be auto detected from the first row.
>    If the row is a one-dimensional array then headers is a no-op
>    If the row is an object then the keys will be used
```

You set "headers" to true, which might cause the first data row to be interpreted as headers, which means, that if multiple columns have a "null" value as data value, that these columns would be merged and you loose the data.

But without additional information it is really hard to say something. Post your console.log of the first 10 data entries to check.

Try excluding headers, by setting

```
.write(data, { headers: false })
```

Comment: sorry, it's not working. the console log doesn't return the missing columns, So I think the problem is before fastcsv

Answer (score 0):

From The Docs:

alwaysWriteHeaders: {boolean} = false: Set to true if you always want headers written, even if no rows are written.
NOTE This will throw an error if headers are not specified as an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `csvWriter` instead of `fastCSV` following 

First install this node package .
 `csvWriter` `npm i csv-writer --save`  ([Link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-writer))


Then in your index.js or where you want your function . Write the following code.

```
const createCsvWriter = require('csv-writer').createObjectCsvWriter;
client
.db("mydb")
.collection("mycsv")
.find({})
.toArray((err, data) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data); //data must be an array of objects
    const csvWriter = createCsvWriter({
        path: './std_folder/Hanuman Madhi.csv',

        header: [
        {id: 'name', title: 'Name'}, //here id means the key of object and title means the header name displayed on the very first row of csv
        {id: 'std', title: 'Std'},
        {id: 'address', title: 'Address'},
        ]
    });



    csvWriter
    .writeRecords(data)
    .then(()=> console.log('The CSV file was written successfully'));
     client.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide exact names of keys inside your collection to get around this issue

fast-csv then will match each key with values inside every document & show every values for which you have specified keys as follows,

change this line where you specify headers as following

```
  .write(data, { headers: ["_id","name","age","contact"] }) // make sure each value inside array is exactly same as you have inside your mongodb collection
```

hope this helps

Comment: the problem is on the find collection

Comment: Please share the sample json you are getting from find collection query, that'd be helpful